# Gutter widths in Susy 2

Tags: sass, susy-compass

In beta 2 of Susy 2, is it possible to set gutter widths in the main grid settings like so:?

```
$susy: (
  flow: ltr,
  math: static,
  output: float,
  gutter-position: after,
  container: auto,
  container-position: center,
  columns: 12,
  gutters: .25,
  !!!!gutter-override: 20px,!!!!
  column-width: 77.5px,
  global-box-sizing: border-box,
  last-flow: to,
  debug: (
    image: hide,
    color: rgba(#66f, .25),
    output: background,
    toggle: top right,
  ),
);
```

Because it doesn't seem to like it. I need to set explicit widths for columns and gutters for this grid and the container should be determined from those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Susy Next, gutters are set as a ratio (`.25`) to the column-width (`77.5px`). Given those settings, Susy can determine the gutter-width (`77.5px * .25 = 19.375px`).

By saying you want static math, `.25` gutters, and `77.5px` columns, *you have already set the gutter width*, and the container can already be calculated. If you like, you can use real pixel values to set your gutter ratio:

```
$susy: (
  column-width: 77.5px,
  gutters: 20px/77.5px, // same as ".258064516"
);
```

`Gutter-override` is not a global setting, and won't help you here. That setting is only for spans, when you want to override the global value. Also, I don't recommend sub-pixel settings. Pixels don't really break down, and fractional pixel declarations aren't handled the same across browsers.

Comment: May I use fluid column-width with static gutter in px?

Comment: Yes, set column-width and gutters in the same way, but change the `math` setting to `fluid`. I know that's a bit confusing. We're working on a better way to do that in Susy 3.

Comment: a bit confusing? i'm real confused ;) 

if i want my container always be 100% width of the viewport, but i set a column-width for example 80px and a gutter of 40px/80px that i have 40px gutter. then i have a complete width of 120px for one column. and my maximum container will be 1200px if i have 10 columns... but how can i set the width to 100%? 

a short codepen http://codepen.io/destroy90210/pen/gPMeRb

Comment: I would simply remove the `column-width` setting. You already have gutters set to a ratio, so that ratio will stay the same. Without a `column-width` to calculate from, Susy will default to a `100%` grid container. There is also a `container-width` setting if you want to use it, but there's no need in this case. In your codepen demo, you already have the settings right - just remove the `1200px` from your container mixin.